# Tool to understand/Visualize c# code

Tags: c#, .net

Do you have any sugestions of tools to ease the task of understanding a pile of C# code? Trying to understand a large piece of software written by others Have to do modifications. Any advice on tools that might help in understanding the code/code flow.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! I use VS2010 c# express edition. Prefer a freeware due to some constraints !

Comment: Nclass generates decent UML diagram and its free. If there is something similar pls recommend !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called Code Rocket that will show either a flow diagram of code or pseudo code.  Unfortunately it is not free and is an addin which means that it will not work with VS2010 Express Editions.

**EDIT**
I am not sure if it works FROM C# but NClass is a free tool : http://nclass.sourceforge.net/   that works with UML.  UML is another way to look at how code works and might be worth investigating

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! NClass generates decent UML diagram on importing the dll file

Answer (score 3):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) helps a lot from prospective of navigation, structure of the class, and refactoring.  You can also use tool from VS, such as Class Diagram.  But if you have a lot of classes, that will not help you.  ReSharper is better in this case.  Resharper has great search, such as where the code is used.

Comment: +1 for resharper. In my experience, if the software is that large then the Visual Studio tools don't really help. But being able to navigate round quickly and investigate where various values can come from, how certain pieces of code can be called, etc, is more useful. And resharper helps a LOT with that.

Comment: @lanR a stack trace is also helpful for this.

Comment: Unfortunately It doesnt work with VS2010 C# Express edition :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class diagram in VS 2010. Or the Class View.  This will construct a diagram of all classes if you use the diagram tool, or you will get a tree view of all the classes using the class view.. you can get to these by right clicking on the project name in VS 2010

These will give you an overview of all classes and their respective functions and methods

Comment: Thanks ! But currently I'm using VS2010 C# Express edition so i dont have the option of class diagram tool.

Comment: Can you view the class view Ctrl+Shift+C

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, it usually helps me to run the program and learn what it does in detail. If you are experienced in the language and platform, this will give you a good starting point. I then start at Main and work down. I get out a sheet of paper and draw out any inheritance diagrams for any OO stuff I find. The best is usually to work through it in an orderly fashion. I then start at the constructor and work down in the order that each method is called. I then do the same for event handlers. Always, learn as much as possible about the overall architecture before doing much editing. The object browser is sometimes helpful, if the previous writers used the xml documentation functionality in visual studio. At the heading of each class I write down the general gist of what that class does. I do all of this before I touch the code. I don't know of any tools.

To ease the situation for future readers of your code. Comment everything that isn't 100% obvious. VS has the nice /// feature for documentation.

Comment: Thanks ! If i try to write down in paper , but debugging i end up hitting message loops and i'm losing the flow of it. Any ideas ?

Comment: message loops? Do you mean event handlers get called?

Comment: Do you know how to read the designer.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate has that kind of visualization tools to show relationships between classes, assemblies, and so on. But I believe it costs a lot.

Comment: I think the questioner is looking for a free tool and is using VS2010 Express.

Comment: Actually, you can use trial version of VS 2010 Ultimate for 30 days. So I think it will work for the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the express version is extremely limited that is why it is free. If yuo are a student goto www.dreamspark.com and you can download the full professional version for free after proof that you are a student you need a .edu address.

We use resharper here at work and it has made navigating code amazing.. DX has a few cool programs also like code rush but Resharper has much better hot keys and navigational control..

Imaging ctrl clicking on a type and having it take you to its implemntation and being able to press alt+f7 and having all the usages pop up.. i had a rough time understanding how to navigate code but this application has worked miracles.

check this post out for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169310/is-using-resharper-a-time-saver
(now deleted but archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20090729081054/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169310/is-using-resharper-a-time-saver)